# What are the possible eigenvalues of matrix $A$ that satisfies $A^2=-I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be a matrix such that $A^2=-I$, where $I$ is identity matrix. What are the possible eigenvalues of $A$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$. (Also, if $A$ is real but you want to include complex eigenvalues, it's useful to know that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a real matrix $A$, then (1) so is its complex conjugate $\bar{\lambda}$, and (2) $\lambda$ and $\bar{\lambda}$ have the same multiplicity.)

Answer (score 1):

Because $A^2=-I$, the minimal polynomial of $A$ has to divide $f(x)=x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i)$. So all of the possible eigenvalues for $A$ are $\{i\}$, $\{-i\}$, or $\{i,-i\}$.

Comment: What should be the order of such matrices?